# VBScript not returning an array through a class

Tags: arrays, class, vbscript

I just inherited an old project to maintain using asp and vbs.  In vbs it passes back a single object and i need to make this into an array and everything I have tried ends up giving me a critical exception.  I have my SQL read going from a single record into an array but I can't pass it back to my main object where I need it and nobody on my project knows vbs.

```
Class LoadFileBS
   Public Function getDocument(req, userProfile)
      Dim dao
      Set dao = new FileDAO   'define my class

      Dim document
      Set document = dao.retrieve(fileId) 'this was a single return that i'm trying to make into an array

If (checkAuthorization(document(1)) = true) Then 'tried making document an array and that didn't work for me.  The (1) was a test to just try and get the array working in this class and not meant as finalized code.
```

---

```
Class FileDAO
   Public Function Retrieve(fileId)
       'Run the query and return the results
       Set Retrieve = runDocumentQuery(fileId)      
   End Function

   Private Function runDocumentQuery(fileId)
      ... 'making SQL call and it returns and i fill document with the info.
      Dim document
      Set document = new DocumentTO
      Call document.setFileId(Trim(rs.fields(SQL_FILE_ID).value))
      ...
      Set documents(UBound(documents)) = document
      rs.MoveNext
      If (NOT rs.Eof) Then
        ReDim Preserve documents(UBound(documents) + 1)
      End If
      ...  'now try and return
      If (isObject(documents(1))) Then    
        Set runDocumentQuery = documents   '<-- array with multiple records
      Else
        Set runDocumentQuery = nothing
      End If
   End Function
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays aren't objects, so you don't use the `Set` statement. They can *contains* object references, however.

```
If (isObject(documents(1))) Then
    runDocumentQuery = documents    ' Return the array (removed "Set" here)
Else
    runDocumentQuery = Array()      ' Return empty array? Up to you.
End If
```

Then you'll need to do the same for your `Retrieve` function:

```
Public Function Retrieve(fileId)
    'Run the query and return the results
    Retrieve = runDocumentQuery(fileId)    ' (Removed "Set" here)
End Function
```

And, finally, back to your original call:

```
Dim document
document = dao.retrieve(fileId)    ' (Removed "Set" here)
```